# Posso usar "prego" al posto di "per favore"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Sto imparando l'italiano, e ho imparato che la parola per "please" è "per favore".  Ma io abito a Roma, e non sento spesso questa parola. Il mio italiano non è buono, ma credo di aver sentito "prego" al posto di "per favore". È possibile? Posso usare "prego" per dire "please"?

Comment: L'uso di "prego" al posto di "per favore" è molto formale e raramente usato. In Italia, specialmente al Sud, siamo molto informali (leggi maleducati) e "per favore" è spesso omesso, a meno che ci si  rivolga ad estranei o persone di un certo riguardo. Con estranei intendo persone incontrate per caso, non commessi o altre persone addette al pubblico. Io vivo in UK e quando torno in Italia "scusi" e "per favore" suonano un po strani e innaturali.

Comment: @algiogia: Non so quale sia il tuo campione. Io e le persone che vedo in giro diciamo “grazie”, “prego” etc. anche al barista che porge il cappuccino o al giornalaio che dà il resto. Ma tutto questo non c'entra con la domanda, ovviamente.

Comment: @DaG mi riferivo all'uso di "prego" nel senso di "per favore". Mai sentito qualcuno chiedere "Mi scusi, mi fa un caffe?" o "Prego, mi da un etto di crudo?". "Grazie" per fortuna è ancora di moda ;-)

Comment: @algiogia: Sì, sul “prego” nel senso di “per favore” sono d'accordo con te! Mi riferivo solo al tuo pessimismo su «"per favore" è spesso omesso ... in Italia "scusi" e "per favore" suonano un po strani e innaturali».

Comment: Dalle mie parti (provincia di Napoli) lo sento sempre piu raramente. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, ma dipende dal contesto: **prego** si usa generalmente in risposta ad un "grazie". Oppure in modo più formale, per esempio nel fare un'offerta *"Prego, si accomodi"* oppure nel fare una richiesta formale: *"Prego, potrebbe indicarmi la via per...?"*

Un esempio:
*"Please, can you help me?"* lo puoi tradurre come *"Scusi, può aiutarmi?"* ma se vuoi usare il termine *prego* diventerebbe *"Prego, mi potrebbe aiutare?"*; utilizzando il termine **prego** la frase diventa più formale.